# php if/else shorthand fail

Tags: php, if-statement, shorthand-if

Normal expression works fine, shorthand doesn't. Where am I wrong here?

```
if (isset($var)) $value = $var;
elseif ($str !== 'string') $value = $str;
else $value = null;
// works just fine

$value = (isset($var)) ? $var : ($str !== 'string') ? $str : null;
// only returns $value = $str
```

Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping the last part in `(  )` like this: `$value = (isset($var)) ? $var : (($str !== 'string') ? $str : null);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with an extra set of brackets around the second shorthand block, `$value = (isset($var)) ? $var : (($str !== 'string') ? $str : null);`

**Added this side note...**

While it's fun trying to squeeze code into one line, it is often better to write it out so that it's easy to read. Your line of code is compact but takes a while to digest whereas...

```
if (isset($var)) {
   $value = $var;
}
else if ($str !== 'string') {
   $value = $str;
}
else {
   $value = null;
}
```

... makes it very clear what's going on - you'll thank yourself in a few months when you look back at your code :)

Comment: duh! I didn't realize that shorthands could also be nested, thanks Steve!

Comment: @Steve: Nice answer :)

Comment: I second the side note, Shorthand is okay but for readability avoid using it, especially when nesting